# Android modify email account password (non rooted device)

Tags: android

I would like to know that if there is  away I can programatically modify email account passwords in android. SO suppose I create a POP3 account in my mail app. Is there a way I can access this password and modify it? Please assume that the device would be NON rooted. I have been struggling to find any way to do this, but wanted a final confirmation from the community if this is possible or if its a futile exercise.

Comment: "suppose I create a POP3 account in my mail app" -- by "my mail app", do you mean "the mail app that I as a user use", or do you mean "the mail app that I as a developer wrote"?

Comment: Suppose you were a **malware** writer. And you could change user eMail passwords programmatically, without the user even know that. You could then demand a **ransom** if they want the old password restored. This is called **kidnapping** and it's **illegal**.

Comment: Imagine a user has 6-7 email accounts (which in my use case is very possible). Also there is a security policy to change the password every 15 days. Now **Suppose** the user wants to do that, now he has to manually change and manage 5-6 different email accounts. A better way could be to  have a single app wherein just entering the pwd can change it for all his accounts. This is neither **kidnapping** nor **illegal** nor is it ransomware/malware. I understand if android doesnt have a way to do so because of security concerns. The idea was to get a confirmation.

Comment: It would be a major security breach, if you could. It's **not your business** to manage your users eMail accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like its not possible based on my own research.